# PHP- Referencing and appending to a txt log file in separate directory

Tags: php, append, server-side, fopen

As we all do, i'm venturing into another programming venture. I'm hand building a web site using xhtml standard 1.0, CSS, Javascript, and PHP. Nothing special here, but I am coming across a very interesting issue during my PHP development.

I wrote working code to send out emails to the Website contact email, and to the sender trough a form. I wanted to also log these transactions internally at the server. Which should have been easy from what I researched. Here is what I have.

```
    $fileVar = fopen("../data/feedback.txt", "a")
    or die("Error: Could not open the log file.");
    fwrite($fileVar, "\n-------------------------------------------------------\n")
    or die("Error: Could not write to the log file.");
    fwrite($fileVar, "Date received: ".date("jS \of F, Y \a\\t H:i:s\n"))
    or die("Error: Could not write to the log file.");
    fwrite($fileVar, $messageToBusiness)
    or die("Error: Could not write to the log file.");
```

The directory I'm storing the feedback text under would be my public_html (home directory, and then easy peasy...data/feedback.txt.

I'm using the standard permissions...literally nothing special 755 for directories and 644 for files. However, every time I execute I'm receiving the very first error.

("Error: Could not open the log file.")

I need help, more importantly if you know why, can you give me a brief explanation or if you don't have time, can you provide a resource link later? I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Thanks for reading, if I find the answer first, I'll post it up.

EDIT: I've decided to include the entire code in hopes the error stems from above. I will appreciate any information and constructive feedback. I'm not the only one out there, so my question are focused on providing a resource to others as well.

```
<?php
//SendEmail.php

$messageToBusiness = 
    "From: ".$_POST['firstname']." "
            .$_POST['lastname']."\r\n" .
    "E-mail address: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n".
    "Phone number: ".$_POST['phone']."\r\n".
    "Subject: ".$_POST['Please_Choose']."\r\n".
    "Message Text: \r\n".$_POST['Message']."\r\n";

$headerToBusiness = "From: $_POST[email]\r\n";
mail("emailreplacement@gmail.com", $_POST['subject'], $messageToBusiness, $headerToBusiness);

$messageToClient =
    "Dear " .$_POST['lastname'].":\r\n".
    "The following message was received from you by website:\r\n\r\n".
    $messageToBusiness.
    "------------------------\r\nThank you for the taking the time to contact us, our representatives will respond as soon as we have the appropriate information for you. 
    Thank you for your patronage.\r\n" .

    "Business Rep \r\n------------------------\r\n";
if ($_POST['reply'])
    $messageToClient .= "Please feel free to contact us with any more concerns you may have!";

$headerToClient = "From: fakeemail@fake.com\r\n";
mail($_POST['email'], "Re: ".$_POST['subject'], $messageToClient, $headerToClient);

$display = str_replace("\r\n", "<br />\r\n", $messageToClient);
$display =
    "<html><head><title>Your Message</title></head><body><tt>".
    $display.
    "</tt></body></html>";
echo $display;

$fileVar =fopen("../data/feedback.txt", "a")
    or die("Error: Could not open the log file.");
fwrite($fileVar, "\n-------------------------------------------------------\n")
    or die("Error: Could not write to the log file.");
fwrite($fileVar, "Date received: ".date("jS \of F, Y \a\\t H:i:s\n"))
    or die("Error: Could not write to the log file.");
fwrite($fileVar, $messageToBusiness)
    or die("Error: Could not write to the log file.");
?>
```

Comment: Why not just use PHP's loggging routines?

Comment: I apologize, I unfortunately am still new to PHP...as in I started reading about it 5 hours ago. Can you give me a little more info on it?

Answer (score 4):

Missed a `/`:

```
$fileVar = fopen("..data/feedback.txt", "a")
                    ^--- here
```

Should be `../data/feedback.txt`. Without that extra slash, you're trying to use a directory named `..data` in the CURRENT directory. Since that subdirectory is unlike you exist, you cannot open a file in it, hence your "cannot open file" error.

Comment: Wow, that was a dumb thing to do. Unfortunately, that's not the only mistake I made. It's still throwing the error, but upvote for the response!

Thank you, I can't believe I overlooked that! I'm at a loss for the remaining issue.

Comment: Can any one provide a little insight into the design, or maybe the file permissions? The issue still remains regardless of the forward slash error.